# Android app crashing in onPostExecute() without any error

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-asynctask, custom-adapter

I am trying to read a list of monitors that have as attributes registration number, producer owner and so on from a json file which is accessible at this link: 
 https://api.myjson.com/bins/dkit2

I used a toast and also Log.d and i noticed that the json reading works just fine. The elements are introduced in the list. The only thing that is not working is the display of the listView with the element from the list. Is there anything about onPostExecute and listView diplaying that i am missing? 
The display message is "Unfortunately, Monitor_application has stopped". I don't have any logs. There is no error stack or anything. It just exists and displays that message.
Am I doing sth wrong in CustomAdapter?

[SOLUTION] 
I have finally figured it out. I forgot to set one field of the object and when the listView was trying to display that exact field, which had't been set and was left null, it crashed. Thank you all for the time and effort you put in trying to solve this.

I have the following classes:

```
public class JsonReading extends AppCompatActivity {

public ListView listView;
ArrayList<Monitor> lista=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_json_reading);


    Worker worker=new Worker();
    worker.execute();

}

public class Worker extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected  Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        HttpURLConnection connection=null;
        InputStream inputStream=null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader=null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;


        try {
            URL url=new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/dkit2");
            connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            //connection.connect();
            Log.d("JSON","Se deschide conexiunea");
            inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
            inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String line=null;
            StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                Log.d("JSON",line);
                builder.append(line);
            }
            String entireJson=builder.toString();
            Log.d("JSON",entireJson);
            JSONObject monitors=new JSONObject(entireJson);
            JSONArray listaJson=monitors.getJSONArray("monitors");
            for(int i=0;i<listaJson.length();i++){
                JSONObject elementLista=listaJson.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("JSON",elementLista.toString());
                Monitor monitorNou=new Monitor();


                monitorNou.setNr_inventar(Integer.parseInt(elementLista.getString("serviceNumber")));
                monitorNou.setProducator(elementLista.getString("producer"));
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
                monitorNou.setData_intrarii(simpleDateFormat.parse(elementLista.getString("serviceDate")));
                //diagonal
                monitorNou.setDiagonala(Integer.parseInt(elementLista.getString("diagonal")));
                //tip
                String tip=elementLista.getString(elementLista.getString("tip"));
                if(tip.equals("ALB")){
                    monitorNou.setTipMonitor(EnumTipMonitor.ALB);
                }else{
                    monitorNou.setTipMonitor(EnumTipMonitor.NEGRU);
                }
                //owner
                monitorNou.setProprietar(elementLista.getString("owner"));
                lista.add(monitorNou);

            }


        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(bufferedReader!=null){
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(inputStreamReader!=null){
                try {
                    inputStreamReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(inputStream!=null){
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(connection!=null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }


        return  null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //afisare in listView
        if(lista!=null){

        //I believe this is the problem since the listView is not displayed
            listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_json);
            CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_list_item,lista);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

}

In my main activity I am calling the jsonReading activity like this:

```
   public void readJson(View view){
        Intent intentJson=new Intent(MainActivity.this,JsonReading.class);
        startActivity(intentJson);
        finish();
  }
```

The code for the CustomAdapter is below. I have to mention that i use it into another activity and it works just fine.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
TextView mon_nrInreg;
TextView mon_producator;
TextView mon_diagonala;
TextView mon_proprietar;
TextView mon_data;
TextView mon_tip;



public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Monitor> list){
    super(context,resource,list);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_list_item,null,false);
    }
    Monitor m=(Monitor)getItem(position);
    mon_nrInreg=convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nr);

    mon_producator=convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_prod);
    mon_proprietar=convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_proprietar);
    mon_diagonala=convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_diag);
    mon_tip=convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tip);
    mon_data=convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);




    mon_nrInreg.setText(Integer.valueOf(m.getNr_inventar()).toString());
    mon_producator.setText(m.getProducator());
    mon_proprietar.setText(m.getProprietar());
    mon_tip.setText(m.getTipMonitor().toString());
    mon_diagonala.setText(Integer.valueOf(m.getDiagonala()).toString());
    mon_data.setText(m.getData_intrarii().toString());


    return convertView;

}
```

}

The xml for the row_list_item:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_nr"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="numar"

        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_prod"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="producator"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_nr"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_proprietar"
        android:layout_width="232dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="proprietar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_prod" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tip"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_proprietar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_prod" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        android:layout_width="178dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_proprietar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_diag"
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_date"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_tip"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.008" />
      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and also the xml for the jsonReading activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".JsonReading">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_json"

        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="551dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is your app crashing or nothing is displayed?

Comment: Can you please post code of your both xml files activity_json_reading.xml and row_list_item.xml

Comment: Also add crash logs

Comment: The display message is "Unfortunately, Monitor_application has stopped". I don't have any logs. There is no error stack or anything. It just exists and displays that message

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured it out. I forgot to set one field of the object and when the listView was trying to display that exact field, which had't been set and was left null, it crashed. Thank you all for the time and effort you put in trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

once try add those lines in try catch :

```
mon_nrInreg.setText(Integer.valueOf(m.getNr_inventar()).toString());
mon_diagonala.setText(Integer.valueOf(m.getDiagonala()).toString());
```

to

```
try{
mon_nrInreg.setText(Integer.valueOf(m.getNr_inventar()).toString());
mon_diagonala.setText(Integer.valueOf(m.getDiagonala()).toString());
}
catch(Exception e){
Log.e("crash_reason",e.toString()+"");
}
```

Comment: I have done this also, but there is no exception. As I explained in the beginning the objects are created, the fields are correctly set, the items are added to the list. I have user an AlertDialog.Builder to display the items in the list and it all works fine except the fact that i need them to be displayed in the listView and that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

might be a problem with running ui operations on a seperate thread. all ui operations need to run on the main thread. Try putting this around the work you do in postexecute.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    //Whatever task you wish to perform
  }
});
```

Comment: i suggest putting breakpoints and/or log.d in postexecute and in the adapter to see exactly which line is crashing. also make sure to clean and remove the old installation from device/simulator, i have had cases here the layout files were not updated so some references just did not exist in the compiled version which caused crash.